# css effect on daterangepicker not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, datepicker

I am using daterangepicker on my website which is working locally but not on the server.

**HTML**

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    } );
    </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
   </html>
```

It's working locally, but not on the server. This is the output on the local server:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTddZ.png)
And this is the output on the server:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI0GA.png)

Comment: Do you see a 404 for the datepicker.css file in your dev tools?

Comment: that css file is of no use. i am not using any css file for it. it is working on jquery and some of the jquery links and scripts.

Comment: Are any of the jQuery scripts or links getting a 404 in your dev tools?

Comment: Its working on these two tags
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">` and <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: No..i am not getting why the css part is not working on it.

Comment: I see. I hadn't noticed the non-local CSS link and was guessing that it just wasn't loading the CSS at all. I tried to duplicate the problem with your code, but it seemed to work fine. Could you please create a [mcve] and [edit] it into your question using the "JavaScript/HTML/CSS Snippet" button?

Comment: i have done the editing.

Comment: So that exact code, when run on your server, makes the calendar not look right? I still can't duplicate it. But when I remove the link to jquery-ui.css, I get something that looks exactly like your screenshot. Are you using HTTPS on your server? Since the link to jquery-ui.css is HTTP, an HTTPS page might block it.