# Issue regarding text redirect which shouldn't occur

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an HTML text field, and a post button, which you click to make a post. Now, to send this post to the database, I made a separate file called post.php to handle the PHP and MySQL code for that, and for that, I had to keep the HTML elements (form and button) in a form, with an action of post.php. Now, whether the form is empty or not, with the click of the post button, it's redirecting to the post.php page, which I don't want to happen.  what's happening is when I click the post button it's redirecting to the post.php page. It shouldn't be doing that. My posting textarea is on a popup, and when you enter some text and click post, it should close the popup, and display the post (which I will make later), and if you don't enter anything it shouldn't close the popup and display an error message I made by giving it display flex (which I already coded using js). So, basically, if the textarea is filled or not, it shouldn't redirect to post.php page, it should stay on the same page. So, if the textarea Is empty, it should display the error message I made, and I already wrote the logic for using javascript, it shouldn't redirect to post.php page, the popup should remain visible and the error message should display. Now, when text is filled and the post button is clicked, it should close the popup and display the post (which I'll code later), but it shouldn't redirect to post.php page in either case. Here's the code:

HTML (yourposts.php):

```
<form class="popup-form" action="post.php" method="post">
<textarea id="postContent" name="postContent" rows="8" cols="80" class="postContent" placeholder="What's going on, <?php echo $firstname ?>?"></textarea>
  <button id="pos" class="pos">Post</button>
    <div id="noText" style="font-family: 'Rajdhani'; margin-top:95px; margin-left:270px; font-size:25px; border:2px solid black; padding-left:7px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:7px; width:290px; border-radius:10px; background:orange; visibility:hidden; position:fixed">Your post cannot be empty.</div>
</form>
```

Javascript (for displaying error message "#noText", if post is empty) (yourposts.php):

```
var postContent = document.getElementById('postContent');
var postBtn = document.getElementById('pos');
var noText = document.getElementById('noText');
var popup = document.getElementById('popup');

postBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (postContent.value === "") {
    noText.style.visibility = 'visible';
    popup.style.display = 'flex';
  } else {
    noText.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    popup.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

PHP (post.php):

```
<?php

session_start();

// Making Connection To The Database

$dbHost = "localhost";
$dbUser = "root";
$dbPass = "";
$database = "signup";

$connection = mysqli_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $database) or die ("Sorry, we could not connect to the database");

// Posting System

if (!empty($_POST['postContent'])) {
  $post = $_POST['postContent'];
  $firstname = $_SESSION['firstname'];
  $lastname = $_SESSION['lastname'];

  $postSQL = "INSERT INTO posts (firstname, lastname, body, date_posted) VALUES (?, ?, ?, NOW())";
  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $postSQL);
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $firstname, $lastname, $post);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($connection, $stmt);
} else {
  echo "No post insertion, as field is empty!";
}

if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
  echo "";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you include an `action` attribute in a form element, you are telling the form where to post and redirect the user to.

If you would like to stay on the same page, you can remove the `action` attribute. This will tell the browser to post `form data` to the page. To process the data, you will need to include `post.php` at the top of your page.

At the top of your `yourposts.php` page, before the `<html>` tag, insert `<?php include 'post.php';?>`

You can also look into submitting forms with AJAX.

Comment: Hi I included it, but what's it doing now is, the entire yourposts.php page has become post.php. So yourposts.php is now an empty blank white page, which it shouldn't be.

Comment: Never mind. I included it at the bottom and it's working now! Thanks!! However, what's occurring now is, when I make a post by filling in the textarea and clicking the post button, the popup closes, and the data sends to the database. That's perfectly good, which is what's supposed to happen. However, if I then reload the page, another entry of the same data gets sent, which is not good, and isn't supposed to happen. How do we fix that?

Comment: Also, if the textarea is empty and the button is clicked, the popup should stay visible until they enter something in the textarea and then click the button, and only then it should be closed. But now, even if empty, and the button is clicked, it's displaying the error message, but the popup is closing, because of the form and page reload. But this shouldn't happen. So how do we prevent and fix this?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use the "PHP_SELF" method. So if you had one file which has your php and html in it like this:

```
<form class="popup-form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<!--Note the difference in the above line where it changes "action" to PHP_SELF-->
<textarea id="postContent" name="postContent" rows="8" cols="80" class="postContent" placeholder="What's going on, <?php echo $firstname ?>?"></textarea>
  <button id="pos" class="pos">Post</button>
    <div id="noText" style="font-family: 'Rajdhani'; margin-top:95px; margin-left:270px; font-size:25px; border:2px solid black; padding-left:7px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:7px; width:290px; border-radius:10px; background:orange; visibility:hidden; position:fixed">Your post cannot be empty.</div>
</form>

<?php

session_start();

// Making Connection To The Database

$dbHost = "localhost";
$dbUser = "root";
$dbPass = "";
$database = "signup";

$connection = mysqli_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $database) or die ("Sorry, we could not connect to the database");

// Posting System

if (!empty($_POST['postContent'])) {
  $post = $_POST['postContent'];
  $firstname = $_SESSION['firstname'];
  $lastname = $_SESSION['lastname'];

  $postSQL = "INSERT INTO posts (firstname, lastname, body, date_posted) VALUES (?, ?, ?, NOW())";
  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $postSQL);
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $firstname, $lastname, $post);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($connection, $stmt);
} else {
  echo "No post insertion, as field is empty!";
}

if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
  echo "";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection);
}

?>
```

With the PHP in the same page as the HTML, you can call PHP_SELF and it will not redirect the page. [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42677137/prevent-page-redirection-on-submit-form-php) has some more detail on other solutions though personally I think this one is the simplest. All the code I have done will do is stop the page from redirecting, you will still need to add in whatever you are planning to do to close the popup and everything else.

Also, your wall of text at the top is a bit hard to read. In future posts, you should maybe try to separate it with paragraphs.

Comment: Also, if the textarea is empty and the button is clicked, the popup should stay visible until they enter something in the textarea and then click the button, and only then it should be closed. But now, even if empty, and the button is clicked, it's displaying the error message, but the popup is closing, because of the form and page reload. But this shouldn't happen. So how do we prevent and fix this?

Comment: What's occurring now is, when I make a post by filling in the textarea and clicking the post button, the popup closes, and the data sends to the database. That's perfectly good, which is what's supposed to happen. However, if I then reload the page, another entry of the same data gets sent, which is not good, and isn't supposed to happen. How do we fix that?

Comment: @VedhReddy this would be something in your php code, you would want to use the php to not hide the popup or delay hiding the popup until you can verify the information is what you want.

Comment: How would we do that?

Comment: @VedhReddy Well you would want to make sure your function to hide the popup does not get triggered until the php has a chance to verify the input. At this point though, it would probably be worth starting another question if you can not figure that out from what I have put in these comments (which IK is very little)

Comment: Any clue on what the code would be?

Comment: @VedhReddy Well you would want to delay the function that hides the popup from executing until you know the info put into the boxes is valid. If you want any more detail, you should probably start another question specifically dedicated to that. I would also recommend you spend some time trying to do it yourself before starting another question, its more fun and rewarding if you do it yourself though go straight to asking the question if you need an answer fast.